# Killer E2500 network driver

Tags: drivers, ethernet

I've recently changed a motherboard to one that uses new Killer E2500 ethernet controller. My installation of Ubuntu 16.04 however did not accept it as part of the family - I can see no ethernet connections using `ifconfig -a`.

I've read [here](http://www.killernetworking.com/driver-downloads/knowledge-base?view=topic&id=2) that it should have worked out of the box on newer kernels - and I'd assume my `4.4.0-62-generic` should qualify as one?

So, is there any magic command I could do to make my installation rethink the issue and use the correct driver? Or do I have to reinstall / recompile kernel following the instructions from the link above?

--edit

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3
05:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Qualcomm Atheros Device [1969:e0b1] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] Device [1462:7a62]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Eth -A3` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 here you go.